# how to fit the dimension in the autoencoder of Keras

Tags: keras, tf.keras, autoencoder

I am using a convolutional autoencoder for the Mnist image data (with dimension 28*28); here is my code:

```py
input_img = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))

x = Convolution2D(16, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Convolution2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Convolution2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

x = Convolution2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Convolution2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Convolution2D(16, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)

decoded = Convolution2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)
```

I get an error message (with padding ='same'  at each layer):

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_148 to have shape (32, 32, 1) but got array with shape (28, 28, 1)

Here is my model summary:

```py
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_20 (InputLayer)        (None, 28, 28, 1)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_142 (Conv2D)          (None, 28, 28, 16)        416       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_64 (MaxPooling (None, 14, 14, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_143 (Conv2D)          (None, 14, 14, 8)         1160      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_65 (MaxPooling (None, 7, 7, 8)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_144 (Conv2D)          (None, 7, 7, 8)           584       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_66 (MaxPooling (None, 4, 4, 8)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_145 (Conv2D)          (None, 4, 4, 8)           584       
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_64 (UpSampling (None, 8, 8, 8)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_146 (Conv2D)          (None, 8, 8, 8)           584       
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_65 (UpSampling (None, 16, 16, 8)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_147 (Conv2D)          (None, 16, 16, 16)        3216      
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_66 (UpSampling (None, 32, 32, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_148 (Conv2D)          (None, 32, 32, 1)         145       
=================================================================
Total params: 6,689
Trainable params: 6,689
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I know if I change the first layer to

```py
x = Convolution2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
```

It works, but I want to use a 5*5 convolution.

How does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase your last filter size to `(5, 5)` to make this work:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras import Model, Input
import numpy as np

input_img = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))

x = Conv2D(16, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)

decoded = Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='sigmoid', padding='valid')(x)

auto = Model(input_img, decoded)

auto.build(input_shape=(1, 28, 28, 1))
auto(np.random.rand(1, 28, 28, 1)).shape
```

```
TensorShape([1, 28, 28, 1])
```

Or, use `tf.keras.Conv2DTranspose`